# Order of arguments while using "String..."

Tags: java

I was writing a method with a variable number of parameters, using the constructor proposed by Java:

```
public static boolean myMethod(String... strings)   {
    for (String s: strings)    {
         // Applying some logic / treatment on strings
    }
}
```

I was wondering: how does Java behaves with the `strings` parameter ? Does it takes it as an `ArrayList`, or a simple `String[]` ? Is the order of the parameters kept while going through the method ?

---

For example, if I use my method like this:

```
MyMethodUtils.myMethod(first, second, third, fourth, fifth);
```

Am I guaranteed that `first` will be treated first, then `second`, etc ... Or not ?

**Bonus question:** What is the *specifical name* of such constructor `String...` (in Java) ?

Comment: Yes, it's guaranteed.

Comment: Its called varargs, its an array, not a list and it always has to be the final parameter in a method. Yes, order is kept.

Comment: The `main` method of an application uses the same syntax, you can be guaranteed that the order is maintained .

Comment: @Berger "uses" More precisely *can use*. Either `String...` or `String[]` is [acceptable](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-12.html#jls-12.1.4).

Comment: @AndyTurner : Sure, the main purpose was to indicate a very common method that can use this syntax, and whose contract (including ordering of parameters) is well known .

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, ordering is preserved.

This is because `String...` (technically called a [variable arity parameter](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.4.1), but often informally called "varargs") is just syntactic sugar for `String[]`. So:

```
MyMethodUtils.myMethod(first, second, third, fourth, fifth);
```

is identical to

```
MyMethodUtils.myMethod(new String[]{first, second, third, fourth, fifth});
```

(and in fact, you can invoke the latter).

You wouldn't expect an array's elements to change order in any other case, and nor do they with a variable arity parameter.

You can find this in [JLS Sec 15.12.4.2](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.12.4.2):

> If `m` is being invoked with `k ≠ n` actual argument expressions, or, if `m` is being invoked with `k = n` actual argument expressions and the type of the `k`'th argument expression is not assignment compatible with `T[]`, then the argument list `(e1, ..., en-1, en, ..., ek)` is evaluated as if it were written as `(e1, ..., en-1, new |T[]| { en, ..., ek })`, where `|T[]|` denotes the erasure (§4.6) of `T[]`.

Answer (score 0):

> Bonus question: What is the specifical name of such constructor
>   String... (in Java)?

Name of these type of constructors is parameterised constructor only.

The only difference is these are using Varargs.

**Variable Argument (Varargs):**

> The varrags allows the method to accept zero or multiple arguments.
>   Before varargs either we use an overloaded method or take an array as the
>   method parameter but it was not considered good because it leads to
>   the maintenance problem. If we don't know how many arguments we will
>   have to pass in the method, var args is the better approach.

[For More information](https://www.javatpoint.com/varargs)

Answer (score 0):

You will get these parameters in a order in which you have written , by referring your above example i can say ,

First will be first , and second will be second

As Java takes it as a string[]

**Answer of bonus question**

There is no specific name but the parameters you pass in such way is called as "var args"

hope  you satisfied :)

Comment: "There is no specific name" False. [See the language spec](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.4.1): it's called a "variable arity parameter".